# Sending form to mail from custom module fails without error

Tags: forms, emails

I've created a module with a form and a block.

When I push the subscribe button, the submitForm function is executed.

The successmessage is shown, but no e-mail is send ...

There are no errors reported in the recent logmessages or in on the server in the folder /logs.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        /**
         * @var MailManager $mailer
         */
        $mailer = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');

        $email = $form_state->getValue('email');
        $params['context']['subject'] = "Subscribe newsletter";
        $params['context']['message'] = 'Someone subscribed: ' . $email;
        $params['email'] = $email;

        try {
            $response = $mailer->mail('my_module', 'subscribe', 'to@email.com', 'nl', $params);
            if ($response) {
                $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('You are successfully subscribed to our newsletter with your e-mail: @email', ['@email' => $email]));
            } else {
                $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('There was an error.'));
            }
        } catch (MailHandlerException $e) {
            \Drupal::logger('mailinglist_send_mail_error')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($e, true) . '</code></pre>');
        }

    }
```

Comment: While logged out, if you go to `/user/password` and try to reset your password, do you get an e-mail?

Comment: Mustn't it be just `$params['subject']` and `$params['message']` without `'context'`? And `to@email.com` be replaced with the `$email` value?

Comment: @NoSssweat that is not working indeed ...

Comment: Did you implement hook_mail in your module?

Comment: @Lance Check the spam box just in case, but if still nothing, then your server is not setup to sendout e-mails. I suggest you use a 3rd party "SMTP service", rather then setting up your server as it's time consuming and you also need to make sure you configure it securely.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong is that required and if so, where to place the hook_mail function? In the same class as the submitForm function?

Comment: The SPF record was not correct. Due to this it was marked as spam. cPanel Track Delivery. That is ok, it is now received, but the mail is empty ... even without the context, it is still empty ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you implement hook_mail in your module? – Alfred Armstrong
>
> where to place the hook_mail function? – Lance

Goes in the .module file. Ex: **my_module.module**

```
/*
* Implements hook_mail().
*/
function my_module_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch($key) {     
    case 'my_module':
      $options = [
        'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
      ];
      $message['subject'] = t('@title', ['@title' => $params['context']['subject']], $options);
      $message['body'][] = t('@body', ['@body' => $params['context']['message']], $options);         
      break; 
  }
}
```

Flush all caches so hook gets picked up.